# How do I get a scroll bar to appear on my DIV while at the same time centering it on my screen?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, scrollbar, center

I’m styling an unordered list, the structure of which is

```
<div class="select-styled active">Arizona</div><ul class="select-options" style="display: block;"><li rel="">Select State</li><li rel="3526">Alabama</li><li rel="3556">Alaska</li><li rel="3547">Arizona</li><li rel="3510">Arkansas</li><li rel="3542">California</li>…<li rel="3554">Wyoming</li></ul></div>
```

There are usually more options than there’s room on the screen to display, which is fine — usually there’s a way to scroll.  However, when I add a div container to center everything …

```
<div id="profileContainer">
<div class="profileField address">
<div class="select-styled active">Arizona</div><ul class="select-options" style="display: block;"><li rel="">Select State</li><li rel="3526">Alabama</li><li rel="3556">Alaska</li><li rel="3547">Arizona</li><li rel="3510">Arkansas</li><li rel="3542">California</li>…<li rel="3554">Wyoming</li></ul></div>
</div>
</div>
```

with this style

```
#profileContainer {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 720px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

But now there’s no way to scroll.  Here's my JSFiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/d2r50gc1/.  How can I center my items in the center of the screen and also have a scroll bar on the unordered list so that I can see all the items?

Comment: Find a different centering method? Is the menu **supposed** to stuck in the middle of the page regardless? Perhaps `absolute` rather than `fixed....but your wrapper is collapsing either way.

Comment: I changed the value from "fixed" to "absolute" and although I can now scroll, the entire screen is scrolled as opposed to just the DIV where I would like the scroll bar to occur -- https://jsfiddle.net/d2r50gc1/1/ .

Comment: @Mike I realize now after reading your comment here that you seem to want the div to scroll internally. I think you'll find that my answer is a more user-experience friendly solution versus scrolling the entire containing div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've accomplished what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/d2r50gc1/11/

All you need to do is apply a few styles to the unordered list:

```
ul.select-options {
    max-height: 15em;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

By using `em` (or `rem`) units instead of `px` you retain support for users who choose to alter their font size which I noted you expressed interest in on another answer's comments. You can alter that `15em` which is an arbitrarily chosen multiplier to any number as you see fit. You might also consider using `rem` instead of `em` but you'll have to make that decision on your own dependent on your final desired use case. If you change the `padding` definition to also use `em` or `rem` you can use math to set the size to always show a certain number of elements in the drop down.

Comment: Yup, taht was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just updated your jsfiddle

You just have to add the height and the overflow to your #profileContainer

[Update](https://jsfiddle.net/d2r50gc1/3/)

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Its not an option to add a fixed height as there will be a variable number of elements in the container and I don't want to constantly have to adjust the fixed height (also when users adjust font size that will screw up the display of the other elements).  I adjusted the fiddle with your overlfow -- https://jsfiddle.net/d2r50gc1/4/ , but the menu still does not extend beyond the boundary of the container with a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suhvalentine/mvt51qn2/66/) with respect to your demands.

```
.select {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(50% + 110px));
    transform: translateX(calc(50% + 110px));
}
```

*Description*

I added overflow to the *.select* class and then used the transform to center it.  Hope this meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a second answer now that I think I understand what you're asking for. I do sincerely encourage you to review my other answer first, I think you will find it to be a far superior option.

Scrolling div.profileField Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d2r50gc1/12/

Achieved with the following CSS:

```
div.profileField {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieved something like this

```
.select-options{ height:60%; overflow-x: hidden;} Add this properties in same class
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qdx5uqrm/)

Comment: You have the scrollbar on the container but I would like the scrollbar only on the element (DIV with the states) in its expanded form.  I tried adding "overflow:scroll;" to the intended element, but no scrollbar is appearing -- https://jsfiddle.net/d2r50gc1/13/ .